# Como verificar se uma DIV tem um ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem alguma forma de verificar se um div possui um id, usando jQuery?

Eu sei verificar se ele possui um valor da ID, assim:

```
<div id="main">...</div>

if ($("#main").length){
// resto do código aqui
}
```

Mas o que eu preciso e saber se a `DIV` tem um `id` dentro dela.

EXEMPLO 1:
Tenho a seguinte `div`

```
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Aqui o jQuery tem que me falar que não tem `id`

EXEMPLO 2:
Tenho a seguinte `div`

```
<div class="menu" id='4'></div>
```

Aqui o jQuery tem que me falar que a div tem um `id`

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi o que quer... para mim que o que disse que voce quer fazer, é o que voce esta fazendo

Comment: alterei minha pergunta, olha se vc entendeu agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ID é um atributo do HTML, então há várias maneiras de verificar. Usa a que for mais útil:

#### `.attr()`

Usando o *getter* de atributos do jQuery:

```
if ($('.menu').attr('id')) {
    // ele tem ID
} else {
    // ele não tem ID
}
```

#### `.getAttribute()`

Usando o *getter* de atributos nativo de JavaScript:

```
if (el.getAttribute('id')) {
    // ele tem ID
} else {
    // ele não tem ID
}
```

#### `.id`

Verificando o estado da propriedade `id`, útil por ser curto de escrever, essencial em casos onde o ID não seja o mesmo que foi escrito no HTML:

```
if (el.id)) {
    // ele tem ID
} else {
    // ele não tem ID
}
```

#### `[id]`

Usando seletores de CSS para ir buscar o primeiro elemento com classe `.menu` que tenha ID. Com `.querySelectorAll` podes receber uma coleção

```
if (document.querySelector('.menu[id]'))) {
    // ele tem ID
} else {
    // ele não tem ID
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer isso em uma tabela, mas esta dando errado. Poderia me ajudar? segue o link https://jsfiddle.net/d0e23b0a/

Comment: @HugoBorges usando uma das soluções da minha resposta: https://jsfiddle.net/gbxqwoqk/

Comment: vlw muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Acho que se entendi a sua pergunta, com o `attr` você consegue isso

```js
// verifica se a classe main possui um id
if ($(".main").attr("id")){
alert("Classe main tem id");
}
else{
alert("Classe main nao tem id");
}
if($(".main2").attr("id")){
alert("Classe main2 tem id");
}
else{
alert("Classe main2 nao tem id");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">...</div>
<div class="main2" id="stack">...</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: isso mesmo, obrigado