# Pegar Value de um Array de Inputs

Tags: javascript

Bom dia

Como pegar o valor de inputs iguais ao clicar na linha.

```js
function getValor(){
 var valor = $('.produtos').val();
  alert(valor)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button" onclick="getValor()">
<input value="2" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button" onclick="getValor()">
<input value="3" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button" onclick="getValor()">
<input value="4" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button" onclick="getValor()">
<input value="5" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button" onclick="getValor()">
```

Answer (score 5):

Podes passar o `this` como argumento dessa chamada da função e assim aceder ao valor desse botão.

Exemplo:

```js
function getValor(input) {
  var valor = input.value;
  alert(valor);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" type="button" onclick="getValor(this)">
<input value="2" type="button" onclick="getValor(this)">
<input value="3" type="button" onclick="getValor(this)">
<input value="4" type="button" onclick="getValor(this)">
<input value="5" type="button" onclick="getValor(this)">
```

Outra maneira seria mais *"à lá jQuery"* assim:

```js
function getValor() {
  var valor = this.value;
  alert(valor);
}
$('.produtos[name="valor[]"]').click(getValor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button">
<input value="2" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button">
<input value="3" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button">
<input value="4" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button">
<input value="5" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="button">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio

Comment: @frodrigues juntei mais uma opção

Comment: Se a resposta estiver correta não te esqueças de marcar com o certo.

Comment: Não ficou legal a postagem nao, mas na verdade quero pegar o valor de uma imagem ao clicar nela. Como seria

Comment: Ola @frodrigues, me parece que você ainda esta com dificuldades, acho que você quer usar o jQuery dentro da função, se esse for o caso, utilize o primeiro exemplo do @Sergio basta você passar `input` para o *selector* do jQuery, ficando assim `$(input)` assim você vai conseguir usar `$(input).val()`, digo isso porque você esta tentando editar essa resposta para colocar o código da pergunta, se ainda existe alguma duvida comente na resposta ou edite sua pergunta.

Comment: @frodrigues a minha resposta responde à tua pergunta. Se o teu problema é outro deves fazer outra pergunta. Não podes colocar uma pergunta com o problema `A` e esperar que eu responda com solução para o problema `B`... se queres o atributo de uma imagem podes usar algo como https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197703/129

Comment: ok. Farei outra. Obrigado pela ajuda.