# Como recuperar um value de um input pelo button

Tags: javascript

```js
function getValor(){
 var valor = $('.produtos').val();
  alert(valor)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor()">GetValor</button>
<input value="2" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor()">GetValor</button>
<input value="3" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor()">GetValor</button>
<input value="4" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor()">GetValor</button>
<input value="5" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor()">GetValor</button>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar Value de um Array de Inputs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382579/pegar-value-de-um-array-de-inputs)

Answer (score 2):

Para o seu cenário utilize a função do JQuery [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/). Esta função retorna o elemento irmão precedente.

```js
function getValor(button) {
    const $button  = $(button); //Convertendo objeto JS para objeto JQuery
    const value = $button.prev().val(); //Utilizando método prev() e val() do JQuery
    alert(value);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button><br>
<input value="2" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button><br>
<input value="3" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button><br>
<input value="4" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button><br>
<input value="5" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text"><button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button>
```

Comment: +1 Tinha me esquecido do `.prev()`

Comment: Obrigado Victor Carnaval

Comment: De nada @frodrigues. Se a resposta foi útil, marque-a como Melhor resposta para fechar a questão. Prazer!!!

Comment: @IcaroMartins, aprendi agora pouco lendo a documentação kkk, nunca cheguei a utilizar mais já tenho uma carta na manga.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso e colocando um *container* por fora do `input` e `button` para agrupar, e modificando um pouco seu javascript veja abaixo

```js
function getValor(button){
   var $button = $(button),
       $input = $button.parent().find("input"),
/// ;                     ^             ^ buscar por input
/// ;                     pega a div que esta agrupando
       valor = $input.val();
   alert(valor)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input value="1" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text">
    <button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input value="2" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text">
    <button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input value="3" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text">
    <button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input value="4" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text">
    <button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input value="5" name="valor[]" class="produtos" type="text">
    <button onclick="getValor(this)">GetValor</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Icaro Martins